# Download Image from Keywords

Tags: images, search, scraping, google-search

I have around 50000 sentences, I want relevant images closely or partially related to those sentences.
 Before **google image search APIv1** was best suited for my need as now it is *deprecated* need to find alternative.

Google encourages us to use their [custom search API](http://developers.google.com/custom-search) (which now supports images), but that costs $250 for 50,000 queries.

I'm looking for something cheaper.

Comment: You may be able to use a library like scrappy and just do google image searches directly